# repair orphaned libhdf5.so and libhdf5_hl.so libraries leads to Caffe compilation errors

Tags: compiler-errors, caffe, hdf5

In my /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory were two libraries in red,

```
 libhdf5.so and libhdf5_hl.so
```

My understanding is that these are orphaned symlinks.I removed them but now need to make new ones. 
I did find these files

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl.so

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so
```

so I made new symlinks and now they are teal.

However I get these errors compiling CAFFE

```
src/caffe/net.cpp:774:7: error: there are no arguments to ‘H5Fis_hdf5’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘H5Fis_hdf5’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   if (H5Fis_hdf5(trained_filename.c_str())) {
       ^~~~~~~~~~
src/caffe/net.cpp:774:7: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
src/caffe/net.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void caffe::Net<Dtype>::CopyTrainedLayersFrom(const string&) [with Dtype = float; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
src/caffe/net.cpp:992:1:   required from here
src/caffe/net.cpp:774:17: error: ‘H5Fis_hdf5’ was not declared in this scope
   if (H5Fis_hdf5(trained_filename.c_str())) {
       ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/caffe/net.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void caffe::Net<Dtype>::CopyTrainedLayersFrom(const string&) [with Dtype = double; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
src/caffe/net.cpp:992:1:   required from here
src/caffe/net.cpp:774:17: error: ‘H5Fis_hdf5’ was not declared in this scope
Makefile:611: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/net.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/net.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

So did I symlink the wrong files?

Comment: Your error is a bit vague, it is not a linker error but also not directly pointing a missing header. I do think that the latter is the problem. It seems that the compiler cannot find even the signature of the function, which is often done by including a header [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347177/not-declared-in-scope). This does not propose a real solution though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it has nothing to do with the libraries yet, as you did not go to the linking stage yet. You error is due to the compilation fail. See [this issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6550), maybe it will help.